# Replace single quote if it is alone

Tags: c#, string, replace, escaping

I have word `ST.JOHN'S`

If I run this two times(*for argument sake, I have a legit reason*):

```
String.Replace("'", "''")
```

the result will be `ST.JOHN''''S`

How can I replace `'` Single quote with `''` two single quotes **only** when the `'` single quote is without any additional `'` single quotes around?

Comment: What about `YourMethod("ST.JOHN'''S")`? How many apostrophes do you want in your result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), like this:

```
Regex.Replace("ST.JOHN'S", "([^']|^)'([^']|$)", "$1''$2")  // ST.JOHN''S
```

Or like this:

```
Regex.Replace("ST.JOHN'S", "(?<!')'(?!')", "''")  // ST.JOHN''S
```

Either way, this will only replace single `'` characters *not* surrounded by any other `'` characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to assert that the quote is all by itself.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputText, "(?<!')'(?!')", "''")
```

Result:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("ST.JOHN'S", "(?<!')'(?!')", "''")
// ST.JOHN''S

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("ST.JOHN''S", "(?<!')'(?!')", "''")
// ST.JOHN''S
```